# Can not open file for reading in perl

Tags: perl

I have to read in a file in a perl script. I have done what the majority of the resources I have found have told me to do but I continue to get the same error, here is my code:

```
print "Input file name: ";
$file = <>;
open($fileHandle, "<", $file) or die "cannot open < $file: $!";
```

Result:

```
cannot open < scores.dat
: No such file or directory at ./project5.pl line 6, <> line 1.
```

Doing this I get the error every time. Any ideas, I am new to perl so I am prepared for a stupid mistake, but yes, scores.dat does exist.

Comment: For reference: http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to be reading the end-of-line character and not removing it from the variable containing the file name (when it prints the message to say the file doesn't exist, there is a newline between the file name and the colon ":"). After getting the file name, add the line:

```
chomp $file;
```

This will get rid of only newline characters at the end of the string.

Do not confuse `chomp` with `chop` (the latter removes the last character of the string, regardless of what it is).

Edit: thanks to `ThisSuitIsBlackNot` for catching my typo.

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove the end of line character from the user input that you're storing in `$file`.

You can either do this manually with substitution:

```
$file = <>; 
$file =~ s/\n$//;
```

Or MUCH BETTER, use the chomp:

```
$file = <>; 
chomp($file);
```

On a different note, your "scores.dat" file has to exist relative to your current script. If it sits in another dir, make sure you're using a relative path, or append the dir path to your `$file`.

Comment: Should read "relative to current directory". Location of Perl script is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with other answers, use

```
chomp $file;
```

To help detect it use

```
open my $fileHandle, "<", $file or die "cannot open '$file': $!";
```

Then the rogue linefeed (or maybe in future  space) will be more obvious.